# rotate a matrix 45 degrees in javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix, rotation

given a matrix like this one:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

which can be represented as a 2 dimensional array:

```
arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
```

rotate the array so that it is read diagonally at a 45 degree angle and prints out this:

```
1
4 2
7 5 3
8 6
9
```

I spent a while coming up with a solution that I don't even fully intuitively understand, but it works, at least for 3x3 and 4x4 matrices.  I was hoping to see more logical and clean implementations.

Here's my solution:

```
arr = [[1,2,3,0],[4,5,6,0],[7,8,9,0], [0,0,0,0]];
// arr[i][j];

transform(arr);

function transform(ar) {
    // the number of lines in our diagonal matrix will always be rows + columns - 1
    var lines = ar.length + ar[0].length - 1;
    // the length of the longest line...
    var maxLen = ~~(ar.length + ar[0].length)/2;
    var start = 1;
    var lengths = [];
    // this for loop creates an array of the lengths of each line, [1,2,3,2,1] in our case
    for (i=0;i<lines; i++) {
        lengths.push(start);
        if (i+1 < maxLen) {
            start++;
        } else {
            start--;
        }
    }
    // after we make each line, we're going to append it to str
    var str = "";
    // for every line
        for(j=0; j<lengths.length; j++) {
            // make a new line
            var line = "";
            // i tried to do it all in one for loop but wasn't able to (idk if it's possible) so here we use a particular for loop while lengths of the lines are increasing
            if (j < maxLen) {
                // lengths[j] is equal to the elements in this line, so the for loop will run that many times and create that many elements
                for(c=0; c<lengths[j]; c++) {
                    // if ar[r][c], the pattern here is that r increases along rows (as we add new lines), and decreases along columns. c stays the same as we add rows, and increases across columns 
                    line += ar[lengths[j]-1-c][c] + " ";
                    // when we've added all the elements we need for this line, add it to str with a line break
                    if (c == lengths[j]-1) { 
                        line += "\n"; str += line; 
                    }

                }
            } else {
                // when we're headed down or decreasing the length of each line
                for (r=0; r<lengths[j]; r++) {
                    // the pattern here tripped me up, and I had to introduce another changing variable j-maxLen (or the distance from the center).  r stays the same as rows increase and decreases across columns.  c increases along rows and decreases across columns
                    line += ar[lengths[j]-r+j-maxLen][j-maxLen+r +1] + " ";
                    // that's all our elements, add the line to str;
                    if (r == lengths[j] -1) {
                        line += "\n"; str += line; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(str);

}
```

Comment: Hint: If `(i,j)` are indices in the original matrix, you can partition the original matrix by `i+j` and these correspond to the rows of the rotated matrix.

Comment: can you give me an example or reference? I'm not familiar with partitioning matrices..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set It has nothing to do with matricies, specifically; more generally just sets of numbers. E.g. The values for which `i+j=0` is just `1`. The values for which `i+j=1` are `4` and `2`, the values for which `i+j=2` are `7`, `5`, `3`, etc..

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll look into it.  This stuff takes me a while :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main idea is to partition the original matrix indexed by `(i,j)` according to `i+j`.

This is expressed in the code snippet `rotated[i+j].push(arr[i][j])` below:

```
arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];

var summax = arr.length + arr[0].length - 1; // max index of diagonal matrix
var rotated = []; // initialize to an empty matrix of the right size
for( var i=0 ; i<summax ; ++i ) rotated.push([]);
// Fill it up by partitioning the original matrix.
for( var j=0 ; j<arr[0].length ; ++j )
    for( var i=0 ; i<arr.length ; ++i ) rotated[i+j].push(arr[i][j]);
// Print it out.
for( var i=0 ; i<summax ; ++i ) console.log(rotated[i].join(' '))
```

Output:

```
1
4 2
7 5 3
8 6
9
```

---

#### In Ruby

Produces same output:

```
puts arr.transpose.flatten.group_by.with_index { |_,k|
    k.divmod(arr.size).inject(:+) }.values.map { |a| a.join ' ' }
```

Comment: this is awesome!  dont you need to reverse each array though before printing?

Comment: @natecraft1 Yes, or use `unshift` instead of `push` as above. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Better yet, just swap `i` and `j` in the loops.

Comment: nice, where do you work in LA. your profile is funny, I don't think there are too many mathisigrammers out there

Comment: I'm in the exciting city of Simi Valley

Comment: Ah cool never been, I've been posting all these random algorithmy questions cuz employers give me code challenges.  It's definitely fun to learn this algorithm stuff and good to see how the pros do it.  Do you have any book recommendations on how to start learning this stuff?

Comment: @natecraft1 The closest thing to an algorithm book I've read was "Numerical Recipes in C++" - I've learned a lot from just the `algorithm` tag here on SO. People have said good things about [this book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0262033844/) but I can't speak from first-hand experience.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49192/discussion-between-natecraft1-and-matt)

Comment: Yo Matt, did you read my last comment in discussion, or no dice?  I'm dying on this problem lol.

Comment: @natecraft1 It didn't inform me that there was a response. Sorry don't have that kind of time right now. Why not post that question on SO along with your attempt?

Comment: I don't know if it's cool considering I think the question is very specific to that company's code challenge, and I'd basically just be giving it away and maybe they spent time coming up with it.  Also I don't know if it's a SO type of question (is it?) I think it's too involved and not specific, unless there is some easy way to go about it that I don't know about.

Comment: Shouldn't summax be `arr.length + arr[0].length - 1`? Your calculation for it is quite odd- the diagonals are the amount down the side plus the amount down the bottom, but without the corner value being included twice. Other than that, this code seems to work

Comment: @MattFletcher You're absolutely correct, thanks for the catch!

Comment: Cheers for the edit. Do you have any idea how to translate the rotated values back to the original grid by any chance please? I've been racking my brains for about 4 hours trying to work it out- I tried doing a similar thing but in reverse, and it works fine until the "triangle" starts getting smaller again, ie in your 3x3 example the 8, 6 and 9 won't work when trying something on the lines of `rotated[y - x][x] = arr[y][x]`... it's hard to explain. Any thoughts? Cheers

Comment: I don't immediately see any short insights that makes the problem trivial. This would be a good SO question.

Answer (score 1):

### The Idea: Walk the Diagonals and Clip

You could use the diagonal enumeration from Cantor, see [Cantor pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), 
which is used to show that the set **N** x **N** has the same cardinality as the set **N** (i.e. natural numbers can be mapped one to one to pairs of natural numbers) and combine it with a condition that one skips those values which lie outside the rectangular matrix.

The Cantor pairing function *pi* takes two natural numbers *i* and *j*, i.e. the pair *(i, j)* and maps it to a natural number *k*

```
pi : |N x |N -> |N : pi(i, j) = k
```

Use the reverse mapping to get this

```
pi^-1 : |N -> |N x |N : pi^-1(k) = (i, j)
```

i.e. one enumerates the cells of the "infinite Matrix" **N** x **N** diagonally.
So counting up *k* and applying the inverse function will give the proper pair of indices (*i*, *j*) for printing the rotated matrix.

Example:

```
0->(0, 0)  2->(0, 1) | 5->(0, 2)  9->(0, 3)  . . 
1->(1, 0)  4->(1, 1) | 8->(1, 2)   
3->(2, 0)  7->(2, 2) |
---------------------+ <- clipping for 3 x 2 matrix
6->(3, 0)
.
.
```

### Calculation of the Inverse Cantor Pair Function

For input *k* these formulas give the pair (*i*, *j*):

```
w = floor((sqrt(8*k + 1) - 1) / 2)
t = (w*w + w) / 2
j = k - t
i = w - j
```

See the link given above for a derivation.

### Resulting Algorithm

Given a *m* x *n* matrix *A*: *i* from [0, .., *m* - 1] enumerates the rows, and *j* from [0, .., *n* - 1] enumerates the columns

1. Start at *k* = 0
2. calculate the corresponding index pair (*i*, *j*)
3. print the matrix value *A[i, j]* if the indices *i* and *j* lie within your matrix dimensions *m* and *n*
4. print a new line, once your *i* hit the top of the matrix, i.e. if *i* == 0
5. increment *k*
6. continue with step 2 until you arrived at the index pair (*i*, *j*) = (*n* - 1, *n* - 1)

### Sample Implementation in JavaScript

Note: I tried this out in the MongoDB shell, using its print() function.

Helper functions

```
function sprint(k) {
  var s = '' + k;
  while (s.length < 3) {
    s = ' ' + s;
  }
  return s;
}

function print_matrix(a) {
  var m = a.row_size;
  var n = a.column_size;
  for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    var s = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      s += sprint(a.value[i][j]);
    }
    print(s);
  }
}
```

The Inverse of the Cantor pairing function

```
// inverse of the Cantor pair function
function pi_inv(k) {
  var w = Math.floor((Math.sqrt(8*k + 1) - 1) / 2);
  var t = (w*w + w) /2;
  var j = k - t;
  var i = w -j;
  return [i, j];
}
```

The algorithm

```
// "rotate" matrix a
function rot(a) {
  var m = a.row_size;
  var n = a.column_size;
  var i_max = m - 1;
  var j_max = n - 1;
  var k = 0;
  var s = '';
  do {
    var ij = pi_inv(k);
    var i = ij[0];
    var j = ij[1];
    if ((i <= i_max) && (j <= j_max)) {
      s += sprint(a.value[i][j]);
    }
    if (i == 0) {
      print(s);
      s = '';
    }
    k += 1
  } while ((i != i_max) || (j != j_max));
  print(s);
}
```

Example usage

```
// example
var a = { 
  row_size: 4, 
  column_size: 4, 
  value: [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16] ] 
};
print('in:');
print_matrix(a);
print('out:');
rot(a);
```

Output for 4x4 Matrix

```
in:
  1  2  3  4
  5  6  7  8
  9 10 11 12
 13 14 15 16
out:
   1
   5  2
   9  6  3
   13 10  7  4
   14 11  8
   15 12
   16
```

This method works for any m x n Matrix, e.g. 4 x 5:

```
in:
  1  2  3  4  5
  6  7  8  9 10
 11 12 13 14 15
 16 17 18 19 20
out:
  1
  6  2
 11  7  3
 16 12  8  4
 17 13  9  5
 18 14 10
 19 15
 20
```

or 4 x 3:

```
in:
  1  2  3
  4  5  6
  7  8  9
 10 11 12
out:
  1
  4  2
  7  5  3
 10  8  6
 11  9
 12
```

Comment: I feel like this is going somewhere, but I don't understand it and that link takes me to Jay's Field Thoughts which doesn't mention much relevant to this.

Comment: That is really short. :-) I'll change my sample to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
function transform(ar) {
    var result = [],
        i, x, y, row;
    for (i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        row = [];
        for (x = 0, y = i; y >= 0; x++, y--) {
            row.push(ar[y][x]);
        }
        result.push(row);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < ar[0].length; i++) {
        row = [];
        for (x = i, y = ar[0].length - 1; x < ar[0].length; x++, y--) {
            row.push(ar[y][x]);
        }
        result.push(row);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This returns the rotated array, to print it out as you go just replace each `result.push(row);` line with `console.log(row.join(" "));`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

```
var origMatrix = [[1,2,3,4,5], [4,5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12,13], [14,15,16,17,18], [19,20,21,22,23]];

var maxSize = origMatrix.length;//Presuming all internal are equal!
var rotatedMatrix = [];
var internalArray;
var keyX,keyY,keyArray;
for(var y=0;y<((maxSize * 2)-1);y++){
    internalArray = [];
    for(var x=0;x<maxSize;x++){
        keyX = x;
        keyY = y - x;
        if(keyY > -1){
            keyArray = origMatrix[keyY];
            if(typeof(keyArray) != 'undefined' && typeof(keyArray[keyX]) != 'undefined'){
                internalArray.push(keyArray[keyX]);
            }
        }
    }
    rotatedMatrix.push(internalArray);
}

//log results
for(var i=0;i<rotatedMatrix.length;i++){
    console.log(rotatedMatrix[i]);
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86GP2/) of it in action (open the Console to see the results)